# Error al lanzar aplicación: Failure getting entry for 0x7f080095 (t=7 e=149) (error -75)

Tags: java, android

Buen dia.

Tengo una aplicación que funciona bien, sin problema en cualquier dispositivo,. Lo he probado desde android 5.1 hasta 9.0 y en todos funciona, menos hoy, lo probe en un LG X210 con android 5.1 y se cierra al momento de lanzarlo. El logcat no siento que me tire un error como tal, puesto que lo pruebo en otros dispositivos y si funciona.

El logcat me tira lo siguiente:

```
04/29 15:05:27: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk C:\Users\Arturo\AndroidStudioProjects\DelRealAppPruebaGit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk 
Split APKs installed in 17 s 699 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp/com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp.ui.Activity_Login" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 20205 on device alps-lg_x210-C64SK76SWS7LPJYH
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
V/ActivityThread: ActivityRecord{17ca7089 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2271d88e {com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp/com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp.ui.Activity_Login}}: app=android.app.Application@16af54bc, appName=com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp, pkg=com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp, comp={com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp/com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp.ui.Activity_Login}, dir=/data/app/com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp-2/base.apk
D/FeatureProxyBase: FeatureProxyBase class constructor
    getService(), serviceName = multiwindow_service_v1
D/FeatureProxyBase: FeatureProxyBase class constructor
    getService(), serviceName = multiwindow_service_v1
D/FeatureProxyBase: FeatureProxyBase class constructor
D/FeatureProxyBase: getService(), serviceName = multiwindow_service_v1
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/AccessibilityManager: setStateLocked: wasEnabled = false, mIsEnabled = false, wasTouchExplorationEnabled = false, mIsTouchExplorationEnabled = false, wasHighTextContrastEnabled = false, mIsHighTextContrastEnabled = false
    java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked
        at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.setStateLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:553)
        at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.tryConnectToServiceLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:636)
        at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.<init>(AccessibilityManager.java:226)
        at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.getInstance(AccessibilityManager.java:206)
        at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.initViewGroup(ViewGroup.java:536)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:525)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:520)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:512)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:119)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.<init>(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3460)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3846)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2042)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:575)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp.ui.Activity_Login.onCreate(Activity_Login.java:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f080095 (t=7 e=149) (error -75)
D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{17ca7089 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2271d88e {com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp/com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp.ui.Activity_Login}}
D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY_FINISHING handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@2271d88e
D/ActivityThread: ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@2271d88e
Application terminated.
```

El error 'W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f080095 (t=7 e=149) (error -75)', no logro encontrar ese código en mi R.java. Ahora si que no tengo idea de que error pueda ser.

**Edit:** Logre encontrar la referencia en mi R.java. Pero sigo sin saber que hacer con eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: *`W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f080095`* suena a un recurso que falta, ¿no habrás borrado algún archivo?

Comment: Eso pense, pero no... realmente si vuelvo a compilar la aplicacion en diversos dispositivos, corre sin problemas. Hasta hoy lo he probado en unos 20 modelos diferentes, y todos sin problemas, hasta que toco probar en este LG X210 con android 5.1

Comment: Lo que tienes que revisar es si el archivo problemático se encuentra realmente en tu carpeta `res` y si ese archivo es válido. A veces eso ocurre cuando los archivos están corrompidos o no existen. Si existe en `res` puede que esté corrompido y tengas que crearlo de nuevo. Si no existe, tendrás que crearlo.

Answer (score 0):

**Resuelto.** Ese error se lanzaba porque la densidad de pixeles de ese modelo era low DPI. Por lo tanto intentaba cargar las imagenes (El logotipo, osea esa referencia que se muestra ahi, era la primer imagen) que corresponden a ese DPI, puesto que no habia esa carpeta de DPI, pues se tiraba la aplicacion.

En resumen, cosa de organizar bien las imagenes correspondiendo a la densidad de pixeles.